# Internal operation during install/uninstall of update sites in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

In my eclipse RCP application, I need to Enable / disable some functions for specific modules based on the installed plugins through update site. In my application, those functionalities are still enabled for the modules, that i have uninstalled by Help -> Installation Details options. And those uninstalled plugins are still present in plugins folder.
So, Why am i able to access the plugins that i have uninstalled?

Comment: You have already asked this without responding to my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64752202/6505250

Comment: @howlger i have added org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/gcOnStartup=true in config.ini file. But still facing the issue.

Comment: Sure, `conig.ini` is the wrong place to add it. Instead, add it to your `plugin_customization.ini` file.

Comment: Yes, Tried that. Still issue is there. If i add that line, Will it delete the uninstalled plugin from plugins folder?

Comment: Yes, enabling the p2 garbage collector that deletes the plugins that are not required anymore next time Eclipse is started, works for me this way. Could you please also garbage collect your question not required anymore? ;)

Comment: Some thing is missing in my case.